# Constructing numpy array using tile

Tags: arrays, numpy, repeat, tile, construction

My question is: How can I get **b** from **a** using tile?

```
a = np.array([[1,2,-6],[-4,5,6],[10,8,-1]])

b = np.array([
          [[1,2,-6],[1,2,-6],[1,2,-6]],
          [[-4,5,6],[-4,5,6],[-4,5,6]],
          [[10,8,-1],[10,8,-1],[10,8,-1]]
         ])
```

I did it like this, but I want something better:

```
b = np.repeat(a, 3, axis=0).reshape(3,3,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use broadcasting:

```
b = a.reshape((3,1,3)) * np.ones((1,3,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have the good syntax for tile: `b = np.tile(a,3).reshape((3,3,3))`